# compare 2 list and check all the inclusive enteries in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have two list

```
roles{admin, guest, configuration manager}(all the roles of the system)

loggedInUserRoles {admin , guest}(roles of the logged in user)
```

I have a user edit form in which all users are there with a checkbox.

I need to check all those roles that match the loggedInUserRolesList in Angular 4.

Comment: You can use javascript find method to find that the user is in the loggedInRoles list and check the checkbox based on the returned value

Comment: Use two for loops? Or as answered below, `intersection` of the arrays using another library.

Comment: Did any of the proposed solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular then I would highly recommend lodash for array and object manipulation.

You can Use lodash library for this type of operations.

Add "lodash": "4.17.4" in package.json

Use below links for more functions 
https://lodash.com/

example :--

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from  'lodash';

export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

list1 = ['admin', 'guest', 'configuration manager'];

list2 = ['admin', 'guest']

constructor() { 
console.log(_.intersection(this.list1, this.list2));
// this will give you your matched Options.

}

 ngOnInit() {}`enter code here`

}
```

Comment: Yes, but it will help in future operations with objects and arrays.so i suggest this api

Comment: I agree that lodash is great and I use it myself, when need arises. In this case it is not needed. It's like shooting a fly with a bazooka... It is possible that the OP will need lodash in another part of the code but it doesn't mean that he should use it everywhere from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
let checkedItems: boolean[] = roles.map(function(role) {
    return loggedInUserRoles.includes(role);
})
```

This will give you an array of booleans that you can use in your template.